# Is there a way to know how many iterations we have done in a for loop?

Tags: rust

Is there an easy way to know how many iteration we have done in a for loop?

If I have this code

```rust
for line in lines {
    println!("{}: {}", linenumber, line);
}
```

How can I easily get the number `linenumber`? Am I required to use an external counter variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
for (linenumber, line) in lines.enumerate() {
    println!("{}: {}", linenumber, line);
}
```

You can also do

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate itertools;

fn main() {
    for (linenumber, line) in izip!(0.., lines) {
        println!("{}, {}", linenumber, line);
    }
}
```

for more flexibility. This has the advantage of letting you change things like the start and step of the numbering as well as the number of zipped elements.

Comment: Nice, works perfectly! I think it's worth mentioning in the for-loop section of the book

Comment: Do you know how to do this with ranges? `5..10.enumerate()` does not exist

Comment: my bad, it works with parenthesis: `(5..10).enumerate()`

Comment: Regular `.zip()` is in libstd too. Itertools `izip!()`'s contribution is that it allows zipping more than two iterables.